# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)? in Django Vue.js

Tags: python, vue.js, django-rest-framework

I am trying to link vue.js with my Django application but having trouble with URL, I have created my app using Django rest framework, I am new to vue.js and it's getting more complicated for me to find  a way to connect URL to my Django app

views.py :

```py
class DischargeViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = TreatmentGiven.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TreatmentGivenSerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.SearchFilter,)
    search_fields = ('ipd','medicine_name','types_of_doses','route','number_of_days')
```

serializers.py:

```py
class TreatmentGivenSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = TreatmentGiven
        fields = '__all__'
```

routers.py:

```py
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'^(?P<ipd_id>\d+)/dischargedetails/$', DischargeViewSet)
```

urls.py

```py
urlpatterns = [
path('api/', include(router.urls)),
re_path(r'^(?P<ipd_id>\d+)/dischargedetails/$', my_patient.discharge_detail, name='discharge_details'),
]+ static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

vue.js :

```
Vue.http.headers.common['X-CSRFToken'] = "{{ csrf_token }}";
new Vue({
el: '#starting',
delimiters: ['${','}'],
data: {
treatmentgivens: [],
loading: true,
currentTreatmentGiven: {},
message: null,
newTreatmentGiven: { 'medicine_name': null, 'types_of_doses': null ,'route': null ,'number_of_days': null },
search_term: '',
},
mounted: function() {
this.getTreatmentGiven();
},
methods: {
getTreatmentGiven: function() {
let api_url = '^(?P<ipd_id>\d+)/dischargedetails/api/$';
if(this.search_term!==''||this.search_term!==null) {
api_url = `/api/^(?P<ipd_id>\d+)/dischargedetails/$search=${this.search_term}`
}
this.loading = true;
this.$http.get(api_url)
.then((response) => {
this.treatmentgivens = response.data;
this.loading = false;
})
.catch((err) => {
this.loading = false;
console.log(err);
})
},
```

Comment: why are you hitting `^(?P<ipd_id>\d+)/dischargedetails/api/$` as it is , the first part of the url is a parameter, your url should be `1/dischargedetails/api` or whatever value your ipd_id is

Comment: Actually my app generates different ipd with primary key, and ipd is having many to one relationship with treatment given so each ipd have different treatment given

Answer (score 0):

You have api_url twice, once with /api/ in front and once without. That url is a regular expression. You need to be filling in ipd_id with a number. The dollar signs and carets are not part of the URL and won't be found in the JavaScript. They are part of the regular expression. You can't just say search=search_team. You need to properly format your GET parameters. You should set up Vue CLI to proxy to Django at the /api/ route and do the same thing with your web server in production.

I would really take a step back and read more about the technologies you are working with though. You're missing some fundamental things and you don't want to have any security issues when people's healthcare information.